# Tkinter.Получение данных с OptionMenu и последующее их сохранение в переменной

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino

нужна помощь...
Нужно забирать данные из OptionMenu о выбранном параметре(PORT,BAUDRATE) и записывать их в переменные,что бы в дальнейшем использовать в этой строке

```
board = Arduino("115200", port=("COM5"))
```

**Вот нужный отрывок кода**

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from Arduino import Arduino
import time


ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
for port, desc, hwid in sorted(ports):
    port


board = Arduino("115200", port=("COM5"))


head = Tk()

head.geometry('500x300')
head.title('Лаунчер')
head.resizable(width = False,height = False)
head.wm_attributes('-alpha',0.95)

def WinSon():
    head.withdraw()
    win = Toplevel()
    win.geometry('800x500')
    win.title('Набор')
    win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: head.destroy())
    win.mainloop()


canvas = Canvas(head,width = 500,height = 300)
canvas.pack()
frame = Frame(head)
frame.place(relwidth = 1,relheight = 1)


t_p = Label(frame, text='ПОРТ', bg='#A52A2A')
t_p.place(x=65, y=150, width=150, height=30)
PortList = ['Выберите порт', port]
var_p = StringVar(frame)
var_p.set(PortList[0])
opt_p = OptionMenu(frame, var_p, *PortList)
opt_p.place(x=65, y=180, width=150, height=30)


t_bd = Label(frame,text = 'БОДРЕЙТ',bg = '#A52A2A')
t_bd.place(x = 285,y = 150,width = 150,height = 30)
BaudList = ['Выберите скорость',9600,19200,38400,57600,115200]
var_bd = StringVar(frame)
var_bd.set(BaudList[0])
opt_bd = OptionMenu(frame, var_bd, *BaudList)
opt_bd.place(x = 285,y = 180,width = 150,height = 30)


Redo_Button = Button(frame,text = 'Далее',font = ("lucida console", 20,),command = WinSon)
Redo_Button.place(x = 192.5,y = 230)


head.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы достать значение из ваших `StringVar` используйте метод `.get()`

Например, чтобы достать значение из `var_bd = StringVar()` вам необходимо написать следующую команду:

```
>>> var_bd.get()
19200  # текущее значение в дропдауне, который вы определили.
```

Ваша функция никогда не будет прежней:

```
def WinSon():
    print(var_bd.get())  # новая строчка.
    head.withdraw()
    win = Toplevel()
    win.geometry('800x500')
    win.title('Набор')
    win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: head.destroy())
    win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.Мои попытки не увенчались успехом,т.к. я сначала записал эту команду в начало родительского окна,а когда перенёс её в дочернее,засунул после mainloop'а))